# Routing to controller/method/id

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I have defined this route:

```
$route['importador/portes/eliminar/(:num)'] = 'mycontroller/mymethod/$id';
```

Now, if i enter the URL `http://localhost/mywebsite/importador/portes/eliminar/4` it loads the correct controller. The content of my controller is `echo $id;`. And prints always `"$id"` instead of 4.

It's my first route so i must be doing something wrong.

Any tips?

My method on my controller "importador" is:

```
class importador {

   public function portes_eliminar($id)
   {
       echo $id;
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you paste your method to question? Your routes is wrong. And what is `eliminar`? Is it param?

Comment: whats `$id`? Are you assigning value from url to `$id`

Comment: For code block, you have to break double line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your router should be like this:

```
$route['importador/portes/eliminar/(:num)'] = 'importador/portes_eliminar/$1';
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working now! I read the documentation at least 10 times and couldnt notice the $1 instead of $id. Thank you!